# What's the best way stream logs to CloudWatch Logs for a Spark Structured Streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-cloudwatch, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The easiest solution I can think of is to attach an appender for CloudWatch Logs to Log4J (*e.g.*, https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders). The problem is this will not capture YARN logs, so if YARN failed to start the application altogether, nothing would reach CloudWatch about this failure.

Another option is to forward all `spark-submit` output (`stdin` and `stdout`) to a file and use CloudWatch Logs agent (installed on master) to stream everything. These will be simple text though, so I'll need to process the logs and extract date, level etc.

I'm running my application on AWS EMR. S3 logs are not an option as these are essentially archived logs and not real time.